# PHP Price range filters from lowest to highest updated from input

Tags: php

I managed to get all my filters working except for the price range inputs. I tried using

```
AND `price` BETWEEN '".$lowest_price."' AND '".$highest_price."'
```

but that did not help. Here is the conditions:

```
$lowest_price = '0';    $highest_price = '999999999';
if(empty($_POST['lowest_price']) === false){ 
    $lowest_price = $_POST['lowest_price']; 
}
if(empty($_POST['highest_price']) === false){ 
    $highest_price = $_POST['highest_price']; 
}                           
$price_range = "AND `price` >= '".$lowest_price."' AND `price` <= '".$highest_price."'";


mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE ".$category." ".$price_range." ".$order_list." LIMIT 10");
```

Why aren't the items reacting to the input lowest and highest prices?
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what is the type of your `price` field in `classifieds` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your price range is string make it integer first like this

```
$lowest_price = 0;    $highest_price = 999999999;
```

one more think what is the type of your `price` field in database table `classifieds` if varchar/text you must change the type of your column to int/float/double (number format) for comparision.

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` is deprecated now use `mysqli_*` OR `pdo`

**UPDATE 2:**

```
$lowest_price = '0';    $highest_price = '999999999';
if(isset($_POST['lowest_price']) && trim($_POST['lowest_price'])!=""){ 
    $lowest_price = trim($_POST['lowest_price']); 
}
if(isset($_POST['highest_price']) && trim($_POST['highest_price'])!=""){ 
    $highest_price = trim($_POST['highest_price']); 
}                           
$price_range = " AND `price`>=$lowest_price AND `price`<=$highest_price";

echo "SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE ".$category." ".$price_range." ".$order_list." LIMIT 10";

// this will print your query try to run this query in phpmyadmin and see the results

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE ".$category." ".$price_range." ".$order_list." LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: The price field in the database is int(25), and i fixed what you said above but still no luck

Comment: This is really weird, it works fine only if I select a category first or a different item order, but if I start with the price range inputs, it won't make any difference on the page... What could that be?

Comment: i have echo the select query what will be print please show

Comment: SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE `category_id`='1' AND `price`>=10 AND `price`<=200 ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: hmmm I think I know what the problem is. After running it in the phpmyadmin, I noticed I had some columns that were set to 0 (I guess it happened when I was testing stuff) so it just ignored this. Also, looks like some of my conditions aren't working.. time to debug!

Comment: The price seems not to be effecting the query even though it is insert. Should it be type int or something different?

Comment: type of your `price` field must be int/float or double for this kind of comparision

Comment: Okay my price type is int(25) hopefully that is good. That is really strange. When I copy and past the echo into phpmyadmin, it ignores the price for some reason. Any reason why it does that?

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the fact that I have OR and AND here and there? Should I used commas instead of AND in some parts?

Comment: is there records in table in your given price range. check it.

Comment: no it is not.. I put up to $200 but I see ads of $1000+

Comment: can you show me a image of your table data (phpyadmin screen shot of table data)

Comment: problem solved! i had to put stuff in brackets where it was OR... totally makes sense now! Thanks again for your help and efforts!

Comment: yes problem was some thing else in your query. you can see to run this query `SELECT * FROM classifieds WHERE category_id=1 AND price=>0 AND price<=200` see if expected results are shown or not